# Is there a way to print a nicely formatted table to the console?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to print a nice table to the console using the Rust language? In the python world, I could create a numpy array or pandas dataframe to hold data values and then output them to the console, looking like this:

```
       f1          f2          f3         m1          m2          m3  
0   14.000000    3.000000   19.000000  37.000000   28.000000  239.000000   
1   14.279622    4.046231   19.202175  36.720378   26.228172  238.797825   
2   14.530399    5.098601   19.413289  36.469601   24.454171  238.586711   
3   14.755486    6.153470   19.633712  36.244514   22.681652  238.366288
```

Is there a way to do this in Rust with arbitrary precision?

I have looked at the vector and array datatypes. While multidimensional arrays are possible in Rust, I have not really seen anyone print nicely formatted tables like the one above.

Comment: Have you done any searching on [crates.io](https://crates.io)? A quick search found [prettytable-rs](https://crates.io/crates/prettytable-rs) and [text_table](https://crates.io/crates/text_table) which seem promising.

Comment: Oh I see. I had checked on crates.io, but kept looking for matrix or dataframe or array, so I found nalgebra and some other math libraries. Prettytable-rs looks like the most usable one. Thanks.

Comment: I wrote [tabwriter](https://crates.io/crates/tabwriter) which solves this problem by implementing elastic tab stops. All you need to do is write `\t` as a field separator and it does the rest (alignment).

Comment: **Note for the would-be answerer:** software recommendation is explicitly off-topic on Stack-Overflow, if you wish to recommend a library, please explain how this library manages to accomplish this job.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for the info, I did not know that. I was going to write up a solution based upon my experience with both of the libraries above, to compare them. I think that should comply with the requirement.

Comment: @krishnab: If your code can be used without the libraries (for example offline), then it definitely fits; if it requires the libraries but shows exactly how to use them and explain it, it probably fits; if it's just a couple links and a couple bullet points comparing them (no code), it probably doesn't... for everything in the middle things are blurry :D